# How do I add a GradientLayer to a CAShapeLayer?

Tags: swift, linear-gradients

I have a circle shape that I need to add a gradient background to. How do I add a CAGradientLayer to a CAShapeLayer?

Here is the Shape Layer:

```
    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

    circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    circleLayer.lineWidth = 10
    circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    circleLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round

    view.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
```

I want to replace the fillcolor with a gradient that goes from top to bottom and from #444444 to #6C6C6C using something like this.

```
func createGradientLayer() {
    gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
 
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
 
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.redColor().CGColor, UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor]
 
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}
```

Comment: Hint: Color stop positions

Answer (score 0):

Using `mask`?

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

gradientLayer.frame = frame // Set the Frame

gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.yellow.cgColor,
                   UIColor.blue.cgColor] // Set the Colors

gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)

gradientLayer.mask = circleLayer // Set the mask
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I try this I get an Xcode error when I try and set the frame to the circlePath. It says it cannot assign value of type 'UIBezierPath' to 'CGRect'. Any ideas how to establish the frame?

Comment: circleLayer or circlePath?

Comment: use `self.view.frame`

Comment: We are getting closer. I no longer can an error, but the gradient is not showing. I will work with it a bit. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Yes because it’s at the bottom of the view hierarchy, I can’t help you as i don’t have the full code; But hope you fix it.